# How does one find the soil fertility characteristics for islands of Hawaii?

Tags: soil, nitrogen

I am trying to find a way to describe the relative soil fertility   characteristics for the islands of Hawaii, Maui, and Kauai (youngest
to oldest).

I want to know about their nitrogen fixation, soil leaching, and limiting nutrients for each island. How can I find this information?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if these (USDA web soil surveys) will have what you're looking for, but it's worth a look if your not aware of them.  It may be difficult to get State level information, but you can choose any state and define specific areas of interest.  https://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/App/HomePage.htm

Comment: Maybe you could find some useful info from the Hawai‘i Soil Atlas (http://gis.ctahr.hawaii.edu/SoilAtlas). It includes : Fertility Class, Nutrient Holding Capacity, Soil Order, Organic Matter, Soil pH, Shrink-Swell Potential, and Water Permeability.